# Do you need a visa to work for countries remotely

Tags: visas, work, south-africa, new-zealand

I am a software developer and web designer. I would like to know if I need visas (like a working) to be allowed to work for companies remotely through the internet. I understand that if you want to visit the country I will need a visa. But just for working with them over the internet, and them paying you. Do I need a visa for this?

To get more specific, I would like to work for a company in New Zealand, while I live in my home town South Africa. I have been living all my life in South Africa, and I don't have any New Zealand visa or anything.

An add on to that, how would tax work? Do I pay for the tax in the country I am living, do I pay tax for the country I work for, or both?

Comment: You only need a visa to go there physically. Taxes work differently in different countries. Generally (I believe) you pay taxes where you live, so I guess you would pay them in S.A.

Comment: You don't need a visa, as far as taxes are concerned, check out your tax regulations, you will pay taxes in SA but it may depend if it's foreign earned etc.